# How fill circles on openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, computer-vision

Using openCV, how can I fill some circles found using the HoughCircles in C++? 
This Circles will be used to create a mask on a image. 
There is a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can pass thickness of the circle out line to CV_FILLED or -1 to fill the circle like

```
circle(img, Point(50,50),50, Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED, 8,0);
```

See [OpenCV Doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#circle) for more info.

Comment: If you want to create mask image directly draw circle to mask image, why drawcountours ?

Comment: In python a -1 or cv2.cv.CV_FILLED can be used for the line thickness.

Comment: Please, How can I draw a filled circle with color? If I set por example Scalar(255, 0, 0), it draws a red circle contour filled with white always. Can I change this filled color?

Comment: These days it is `cv2.FILLED` in python.

Comment: @obachtos how did you find that `cv2.FILLED` will be suitable? This constant variable isn't not mentioned anywhere in the docs. Is there a list of them?

Comment: @Kari e.g. [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf076ef45de481ac96e0ab3dc2c29a777)